# Mintty terminal emulator: how to use “Image screenshot export”?

Tags: bash, screenshot, mintty

I'm programming in Bash (Git BASH) on Windows Server 2012R2.

From within my bash scripts, I would like to make a Screenshot of the mintty window, I'm running in.

According to https://mintty.github.io/ minnty has the ability for "Image screenshot export".

Does anybody know how to use this "Image screenshot export" feature of mintty?

Using printf '\e[12i' seems not to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "we start in this directory: $(pwd)";

echo "now printing ...";

printf '\e[12i' >/dev/tty; echo "ret1: $?";
[ -t 2 ] && { printf '\e[12i' >&2; echo "ret2: $?"; }
[ -t 1 ] && { printf '\e[12i'; echo "ret3: $?"; }

echo "printed";

ls -rlt | tail -3;
```

leads to

```
$ 99_tmp1.sh
we start in this directory: /d/_bin01
now printing ...
ret1: 0
ret2: 0
ret3: 0
printed
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zzz91289 1049089 48592 Nov  7 10:39 99_cross_const.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zzz91289 1049089  7327 Nov  7 19:54 99_reset_svc.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zzz91289 1049089   419 Nov  7 20:21 99_tmp1.sh

xxxx@Wxxxx MINGW64 /d/_bin01
$
```

But I can't find the screenshot. Not in current directory. Not in $HOME.

Comment: [This site](https://github.com/mintty/mintty/wiki/CtrlSeqs#printing-and-screen-dump) says `^[[12i` is a control sequence to "save screen as PNG image". You can send it from Bash with `printf '\e[12i'`. If there is `/dev/tty` available in Git Bash for Windows (I don't know this) then this is the best file to send to (`printf '\e[12i' >/dev/tty`). The second best choice is stderr, if not redirected to a non-tty (`[ -t 2 ] && printf '\e[12i' >&2`). Finally stdout (`[ -t 1 ] && printf '\e[12i'`). This is not an answer because I have no means to test this.

Comment: Perfect. That's, what is was looking for! Great, thank you.

Comment: I always searched for the term "screenshot", because they described it as “Image screenshot export”.

Comment: Does it work? Should I write a proper answer?

Comment: not yet. I have edited the orginal post. I don't know, if this is against some rules. Couldn't do it in the comment, because I was not able to format the text properly in the comment.

Comment: just found: The HTML page is created in the start directory of mintty and uses a filename pattern of mintty.date_time.html. But this information does not help, because I can't find the screens in the start directory either.

Comment: I will pass then, I have no Windows to test this. If you figure this out, [consider writing an answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: ok, thank you anyway!

Comment: I'm giving up. NirCmd is working fine for me. https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html. 
Exampale: $ /d/_exe/nircmd.exe  savescreenshot "D:\_tmp\shot.png"

Answer (score 0):

#### How to use this "Image screenshot export" feature of `mintty`?

> **Image dump of terminal contents**
>
> Mintty can save the visual contents of the terminal screen in an image file mintty.date_time.png. **This is supported from the context menu or via user-definable key functions**. The current terminal dimensions are used for the image size except in Tek mode, where one of the original Tek sizes is used (depending on whether 12-bit pixel addresses are in effect).

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

> Filename pattern and location are configurable (setting SaveFilename).

Source [mintty](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html)

To save an image using cygwin `mintty`, right click to open the context menu and click `Save as Image`

> [image]

It looks like you can define key function to do this. The key function can presumably be executed from a `bash` script but I have no experience of doing this.

Comment: I'm not sure this is useful. My first impression was that "from within my bash scripts" means "programmatically". I'm curious what the asker will say.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski If you can define a key function to do it then can't bash send that key combination to the enclosing mintty? That's the bit I've said I don't know how to do ...

Comment: @David: This is the answer to my question. Thank's a lot. I will try to check that (sending the key to minnty).

Answer (score 0):

The thing missing for me was to have a `SaveFilename` configured in the *.minttyrc* file.

From the console, type `nano ~/.minttyrc` to open the configuration file in the [nano](/questions/tagged/nano) editor. Add the following line (or change it to suit your needs) and save  ([references and examples here](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html)).

```
SaveFilename=$USERPROFILE/Pictures/mintty/%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S
```

When you open a *new* Git Bash window, it will use the new setting and save screenshots to your specified location/file prefix when you right-click and choose "Save as Image".